# Set the TextBox background color transparent

Tags: vb.net

Is there any way to set the TextBox background color transparent or set a background image or set the background color manually with the hex color code?

[image: Example]

Comment: I'm fairly sure that the standard WinForms `TextBox` control doesn't support transparency or background images. As for the background colour, just like for all controls, you set that by assigning a `Color` value to the `BackColor` property. If you have a hex code for a colour then what you should be looking for is a way to convert that to a `Color` value, which is not hard to find. If you want to be able to assign the code directly, create your own derived class that inherits `TextBox` or write an extension method.

Comment: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4390/AlphaBlendTextBox-A-transparent-translucent-textbo

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know textbox `does not support` transparent color property. **But** if you set the `back color` of the `textbox` to the `same` color as of its `background component`, still it can be considered as `transparent`.

**How to do that -** 
You can get the color name of the background component(in your case it is the form) and pass that name to the component which you want to be transparent.

```
    Dim lname As String = Me.BackColor.ToString
    Dim name As String = lname.Substring(7, lname.Length - 8)
    txtbox1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromName(name)
```

Explanation -

1. The first line in the code gets you the name of the color, but there's a rub, it gets the name something like this - `Color [Dark Orange]` and we need only the name of the color i.e `Dark Orange`.
2. Thus the second line is to get the exact color name by removing this - `Color []` part
3. And the last line to set that color same as of the background component color.

Hope it works, still have problem let me know...

Answer (score -1):

To change the background color manually with the hex color code, you've to convert the hex color code to rgb on the net then use the rgb in here replacing r g b.

```vb
TextBox2.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(r, g, b)
```